# Django Model Inheritance -- prevent subclass instances from appearing in superclass admin

Tags: django, inheritance

I have two classes:

```
class Article(ContentAsset):

    title =  models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    author =  models.CharField(max_length=2000, blank=True)
    source = models.CharField(max_length=2000, default="")
    datePublished = models.DateField(default=datetime.now)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

and

```
class PubMedArticle(Article):
    pubMedID = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    abstract = models.TextField(max_length=20000)
```

All of the PubMedArticle instances show up in the admin interface twice -- under the list of all `PubMedArticle` objects , and list of all `Article` objects. Is this normal behavior? I'd think that a subclass wouldn't normally show up in the admin list of its superclass. What's the best way to ensure that these `PubMedArticle` objects show up only under the `PubMedArticle` admin list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal behavior.  From database point of view table primary key of `PubMedArticle` just refers to  `Article` table. So for each record in PubMedArticle  table must be a record in Article table.

Now to the admin. The are two ways:

1) Make Article model abstarct - a good idea if you dont need unique primary keys to all of your articles.
2) Customize django admin list query.

Comment: Thanks. Now if I make the Article model abstract, will I still be able to add content items that are just Articles, not PubMedArticles?

Comment: No abstract models does not have their representation in database. You could subclass with StandartArticle and make 'pass' implementation.